# sml understanding function compositions

Tags: sml, ml

I am trying to understand difference between these two;

```
val my_fun = length o List.filter (fn (item) => item = #"a") o String.explode
```

This one can be invoked (my_fun "name" will return 1) and works fine. I am trying to understand why following is not working

```
length o (List.filter (fn (item) => item = #"a" ) (String.explode "name"))
```

Definition of function composition in sml

```
f o g = f(g(x))
```

In the second form what we do is ( I think)

```
length ([#"a"])
```

Comment: You're missing the parameter in the composition definition; `(f o g) x = f(g x)`, or `f o g = fn x => f (g x)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be confusing function composition with function application.

Composition is a higher-order function which takes two functions, `f` and `g`, of compatible types and returns another function -- the function which is computed by first applying the `g` to a value and then applying `f` to the result. `o` is a built-in operator, but if you wanted to define composition yourself it would be something like

```
fun compose (f,g) x = f(g(x))
```

this has type `fn : ('a -> 'b) * ('c -> 'a) -> 'c -> 'b` (which is exactly the type you get when you type `(op o);` in the REPL). Note that the return value of `compose` is `'c -> 'b`, which is a function type.

```
length o List.filter (fn (item) => item = #"a") o String.explode
```

makes perfect sense since the types are compatible and composition is right-associative.

On the other hand, as you already note,

```
length o (List.filter (fn (item) => item = #"a" ) (String.explode "name"))
```

would be equivalent to

```
length o [#"a"]
```

That really doesn't make sense. What would it even mean to compose a function with a list. A list isn't a function. It does make sense to *apply* `length` to that list, which is what you seem to expect.

Application is simply juxtaposition, so all you would need to do is write

length (List.filter (fn (item) => item = #"a" ) (String.explode "name"))

Which reduces to `length [#"a"]` and from thence to 1.

If you wanted to write your own `apply` function you would write:

```
def apply f x = f x
```

This might strike you as superficially similar to `compose` but its type is radically different: `fn : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b`. Composition *involves* application, but it isn't the same thing.